# Windows DNS Server Export

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2, dns-hosting

Is there a way or a tool that I can get a csv (or even tab delimited) list of all `Forward Lookup Zone` records and zones in a Windows 2008 R2 DNS Server?

The DNS Server is the built-in Windows one, and shows as version 6.1.7601.17514

I did notice `Export-DnsServerZone` but it looks like it's a per-domain basis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell and WMI.

```
PS C:\>Get-WMIObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' -List
```

That will list the many different classes in the MicrosoftDNS namespace.

Want to get all resource records on the server?

```
PS C:\>Get-WMIObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord
```

Want to get only the A records?

```
PS C:\>Get-WMIObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' MicrosoftDNS_AType
```

Want to get only the AAAA records?

```
PS C:\>Get-WMIObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' MicrosoftDNS_AAAAType
```

Want to export all the A records to a CSV?

```
PS C:\>Get-WMIObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' MicrosoftDNS_AType | Select OwnerName,RecordData | Export-Csv C:\Users\me\desktop\dns.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Want to use a tab delimiter instead of a comma?  Add ``` -Delimiter "``t" ``` to Export-Csv.  (Only one backtick in front of the `t`... Stackexchange markdown can't handle my skillz.)

Want to get all the domains on the DNS server that are forward lookup zones only, and not Root Hints?

```
PS C:\>Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' MicrosoftDNS_Domain | ? { $_.ContainerName -Notlike '..RootHints' -And $_.ContainerName -NotLike '..Cache' -And !$_.Reverse } | Select Name
```

Comment: Keep getting an error when I try `Get-WMIObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord | Select OwnerName,RecordData | Export-Csv C:\Users\me\desktop\dns.csv -NoTypeInformation`   stating `Invalid parameter`

Comment: @Kevin So start backing up from the end of the statement and see for yourself which exact part is causing the error.

Comment: Doing that now... weird thing is, it dumps out a 3+M csv with over 4200 records (which seems right)

Comment: Wow...  it's the first part... `Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root\MicrosoftDNS' MicrosoftDNS_Domain`   Here's a shot of the actual error http://prntscr.com/58mbek

Comment: @Kevin You'll be happy once you update to Server 2012 and can use a simple [`Get-ServerDnsZone`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649861(v=wps.620).aspx).

Comment: Honestly, I can't stand Server 2012.  Too much like Win 8 ;)